# Swap the index and value of integer array

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently working on an enigma-like machine for a hobby project, but I can't figure out how to reverse the encoder positions. The problem is I am trying to swap the index and value of an array.

```
int[] origPatt;
origPatt = R1.Pattern;
for (int i = 0; i < origPatt.length; i++) {
  R1.Pattern[origPatt[i]] = i;
}
```

Here is what I expect it to do, where the index is on top, and the value is below:

0, 1, 2, 3, 4   ->   0, 1, 2, 3, 4

4, 0, 3, 1, 2   ->   1, 3, 4, 2, 0

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{4, 0, 3, 1, 2};
int[] result = new int[arr.length];
for(int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
    result[arr[i]] = i;
}
```

The problem with your code is that you wrote: `origPatt = R1.Pattern;`
instaid of `origPatt = R1.Pattern.clone();`.